# try - throws in IBAction - xCode 7

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I have a problem with the new "throws" - "try" parameters.

I get an Error to add these words and so I added the "throws" at the end of the IBAction Function.

```
@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject)throws {//code here}
```

Inside I'm dong some irrelevant stuff and then this:

```
let jsonData:NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary
```

After that there are no errors but when I run the app and click on the button, the app crashes with the code

> 2015-06-15 10:43:11.374 BottLED[7283:1175818] -[BottLED.loginViewController loginButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fee28da7d20
>   2015-06-15 10:43:11.381 BottLED[7283:1175818] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BottLED.loginViewController loginButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fee28da7d20'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d67c885 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010cd0edf1 objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d684b5d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d5d1e3a ___forwarding_** + 970
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d5d19e8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>       5   UIKit                               0x000000010dc46257 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 125
>       6   UIKit                               0x000000010dc461b2 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 79
>       7   UIKit                               0x000000010dda1422 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
>       8   UIKit                               0x000000010dda16c6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 272
>       9   UIKit                               0x000000010dda08a9 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 599
>       10  UIKit                               0x000000010dcacbe8 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
>       11  UIKit                               0x000000010dcad7d6 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
>       12  UIKit                               0x000000010dc62705 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
>       13  UIKit                               0x000000010dc3f5df _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6031
>       14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d5a70f1 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d59ceac __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
>       16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d59c363 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
>       17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d59bd78 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
>       18  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000111fdebca GraphicsServices + 52170
>       19  UIKit                               0x000000010dc4479b UIApplicationMain + 171
>       20  BottLED                             0x000000010c7cb9ad main + 109
>       21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011029ca05 libdyld.dylib + 10757
>       22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

when I do some breakpoints and delete the "throws", the app does not crash. I really don't know what to do now.. I hope someone can help me!

The full code is:

```
@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject)throws {
    var name:NSString = textFieldName.text!
    let pass:NSString = textFieldPw.text!
    if ( name.isEqualToString("") || pass.isEqualToString("") ) {
        let loginFailed = UIAlertView(title: "Failed to Signup",
            message: "Please fill in all Textfields",
            delegate: nil,
            cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        loginFailed.show()
    } else {

            let post:NSString = "username=\(name)&password=\(pass)"

            NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

            let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "my url")!

            let postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

            let postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

            let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            request.HTTPBody = postData
            request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
            request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


            var reponseError: NSError?
            var response: NSURLResponse?

            var urlData: NSData?
            do {
                urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                reponseError = error
                urlData = nil
            }

            if ( urlData != nil ) {
                let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

                NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

                if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
                {
                    let responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                    NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);



                    let jsonData:NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary


                    let success:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger

                    //[jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];

                    NSLog("Success: %ld", success);

                    if(success == 1)
                    {
```

Comment: What is your full code? You need to wrap the try in a do-catch block. Are you doing this?

Comment: no I don't. I'll post the whole code in right a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Obj-C `throws` is a syntactic sugar for the Obj-C `error: (NSError **)error` parameter.

When you add `throws` to a method, it is secretly adding the parameter. Your method won't be `loginButtonPressed:` anymore, it will be `loginButtonPressed:error:` (at least for Obj-C). However, when the event is being handled, the system will still look for method `loginButtonPressed:` because that's how the event has been connected in the XIB. The method is not there anymore, so the app will crash with `unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

**Solution**: don't use `throws` in action handlers, it is violating the contract of the method because the system doesn't expect anything to be thrown there. Catch all errors inside your action handler.

```
do {
    urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)
} catch let error as NSError {
    reponseError = error
    urlData = nil
} catch {
   // Catch all error-handling
    urlData = nil
}
```

Comment: And how do I do that? Can you please give an example?

Comment: @LukePistrol Added an example how to catch all the errors.

Comment: Ok. and how to use that on 

let jsonData:NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary

Comment: @LukePistrol The same way, just always add that `} catch { ... }` as the last error handler. You can put an assert there if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can catch the error. You need to take your throws method out of the button IBAction.

Remove throws from the IBAction and create a new method. Then do try and catch the error in the method. Either way, don't throw from an IBAction.